# Show copy of website when MySQL is down

Tags: 7

I'm curious if there is a module or a way to display a working copy of a Drupal website even when MySQL goes down. While obviously if MySQL goes down, it should be resolved, it would still be nice for the customer side and their audience to be able to use the website still.

Has anyone ever done something like this before? You wouldn't be able to login or make content changes of course. Is there a way using .htaccess or something that you could ping the site and if MySQL is down, redirect to a cloned site?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. But yeah, there's [Tome](https://www.drupal.org/project/tome).

Comment: How is it off topic if it's specifically referring to Drupal? But thank you for sharing Tome, wish it was for 7 though.

Comment: "Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, module, theme, distribution, tutorial, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Fair enough, not sure which Stack site this would be OK at then.

Comment: You should migrate your site to D8, now. D7 will be EOL next year.

Comment: Looks like Nov 2021, yeah that is eventually the plan though I need to learn the new D8 module structure. Also it's hard to be convinced to migrate to a version which I find primarily has alpha state modules.

Comment: I think Software Recommendations is good for that. But you could also simply rephrase your question and drop the module part. Still it would be too broad then, but at least on-topic. As long as you not ask for the "best way" to do this. Then it would be off-topic again, as it would attract opinion-based answers... But interesting question indeed. Upgrade to D8 and then do Tome. :)

Comment: "Drupal 7 will be end-of-life when Drupal 9 releases in 2020, but there will be commercial support options for at least another year."

Comment: When you start D8 you have to use Composer now. Quasi standard would be to use this template then: https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project. And you also don't use globally installed Drush anymore. Every project is supposed to use it's own project-local Drush dependency.

Comment: Some CDN's provide this feature.

Comment: There is a maintenance page in the templating system of your theme that can be used for the specific case when database is down (maintenance-page--offline.tpl.php) so you can probably use that to pull content from a static archive.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I think I am going to move this over to Software Recommendations as I can't think of a good way to word this while keeping within the guidelines.